# как добавить сумму чисел в local srorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

я пытаюсь сделать счетчик количества товара,добавляемого в корзину.

Это кусок кода блока,который выводится из js файла:

```
    var sum={};
    var cart={};

function goodsOut(data){
    if(data!=0){
        var pack=JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(pack);
        var out="";

                    out+='<div class="col-lg-12 single">';
                         for(var key in sum){
                            out+=`<div class="val-plus"><i data-id="${sum.key}" class="fas fa-plus"></i></div>`; 
                            }
                            out+=`<a data-id="${pack.id}" class="ad-to-crt pull-right">Добавить в корзину</a>`;
                    out+='</div>';

         $('.goods-out').html(out);
         $('.val-plus').on('click', plusGoods);
         $('.ad-to-crt').on('click',addToCart);
}
```

с помощью этой функции я собираюсь суммировать общее количество id в переменную sum,а затем при клике на кнопку 'добавить в корзину', сумма переносилась в переменную cart, в local storage.

```
 function plusGoods(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    sum[id]++;

}

function addToCart(){
    //добавляем товара в корзину
    var id=$(this).attr('data-id');
    //console.log(id);
    if(cart[id]==undefined){
        cart[id]=1;//если в корзине нет товара-делаем равным 1
    }
    else{
        cart[id]+=sum[id];

    }
    saveCart();
    showMiniCart();
}
```

В этих функциях я вывожу и сохраняю сумму в local storage

```
 function loadCart(){
    //проверяю есть ли в localStorage запись cart
    if(localStorage.getItem('cart')){
        //если есть расшифровываю и записваю в перемунную cart
        cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        } 
        saveCart();           
}

function saveCart(){
    //сохраняю корзину в localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('cart',JSON.stringify(cart)); //корзину в строку
}
```

Никак не могу понять почему при выполнении цикла for key in sum, html совсем не выводит этот блок,который обернут в цикл,может я совсем не правильно рассуждаю, и не стоит оборачивать в цикл. Помогите пожалуйста,задача вроде несложная, но я что то совсем не могу разобраться

Comment: а goodsOut когда вызывается? подозреваю что cart в этот момент пустая просто

Comment: goods out вызывается с помощью другой функции,которую я не стал показывать, думаю в этом нет смысла, goods out вызывается при загрузке страницы